# Creating wordpress dump(.wxr) using unix and mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, unix

I need to create wordpress export dump (.WXR) using SSH on my server. I have lost access to the Wordpress dashboard.Can it be done using some unix,mysql script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [blogged here](http://drincruz.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/wordpress-cli-export.html), all you need is the `export_wp` function, so run something along the lines of.

```
include 'wp-config.php';
include 'wp-admin/includes/export.php';

ob_start();
export_wp();
$file = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$fh = fopen("wordpress-" . date('Y-m-d') . ".xml", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $file);
fclose($fh);
```

Then just grab the .xml file generated!